# ADB requires drivers that are installed, not fastboot though, what drivers are required for fastboot?

Tags: adb, fastboot

I want to use ADB to backup everything on my phone so I can use CFAutoroot and restore root permissions, without erasing my entire phone, or deleting an app. I've had issues with this phone, I still have root access, but my Superuser or root control app is fucked up, to where it freezes or says binary reserved. I don't know how to fix this, so I want to back up my phone with ADB.

So I have used ADB and it restarts my phone adb restart bootloader, but when I use fastboot to flash it waits for devices, and nobody is providing sufficient answers, so I need the help or you guys. I'm trying to flash TWRP to my Samsung Galaxy S4 IGH-I337. It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read this question and answer? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162664/fastboot-on-samsung-devices

Comment: adb backup is running in boot mode. not all apps support it. re-install kinguser apk or whatever gui kingroot provides to grant root access. you can backup apps with Migrate instead

Comment: root goes through but the supersu still says binary reserved or it crashes.

Comment: refer to [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234273/i-rooted-my-phone-but-my-root-is-saying-binary-reserved-as-the-app-was-uninsta#comment310825_234273)